# DataGridView checkbox not showing up when font size is large

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which contains two text columns and one checkbox column. If the user increases the font size in Vista or Windows 7, the checkbox is no longer visible. I set the AutoSizeRowsMode to AllCells and that fixes it initially. However the rows in the grid are editable, and if the user clicks a row to edit it, the checkbox disappears again until row is unselected.

I've not been able to find any resources online regarding this issue so I'm surprised that no one's encountered this before. The row height is set to 21 so more than the checkbox's required size of 17...

This is an Outlook addin DLL so I cannot use SetProcessDPIAware().

Comment: What do you mean by "disapears" when the row is selected?  Does the checkbox column shrink, or does it stay the same size but not show the checkbox?

Comment: It stays the same size, but the checkbox is simply not there.

Answer (score 6):

I've encountered this just now and spent almost an hour trying to figure out where my code was wrong why checkboxes weren't appearing. Luckily in my case setting AUtoSizerowsMode to all Cells seems to fix it, even during edit. (This is on Windows 7(

Comment: This is prohibitively slow with lots of data; AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells performs better.